# How to move products Attributes block after price

Tags: magento2, attributes, product-attribute, custom-attributes

How do I move or show the product attributes currently showing at More Information to after the Price and Availability In Stock.

[image]

Here is the piece that shows the product attributes under More Information tab.

```
<?php
/**
* Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
* See COPYING.txt for license details.
*/

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/**
 * Product additional attributes template
 *
 * @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Attributes
*/
?>
<?php
$_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
$_product = $block->getProduct();
?>
<?php if ($_additional = $block->getAdditionalData()): ?>
<div class="additional-attributes-wrapper table-wrapper">
    <table class="data table additional-attributes" id="product-attribute-
specs-table">
        <caption class="table-caption"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('More 
Information') ?></caption>
        <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($_additional as $_data): ?>
            <tr>
                <th class="col label" scope="row"><?= $block-
>escapeHtml(__($_data['label'])) ?></th>
                <td class="col data" data-th="<?= $block-
>escapeHtml(__($_data['label'])) ?>"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_helper-
>productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<?php endif;?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create one PHTML file in below location

> app\design\frontend\Vendor\theme\Magento_Catalog\templates\product\view\ccolor.phtml

```
<?php
echo $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output')->productAttribute($block->getProduct(), $block->getProduct()->getColor(), 'color'));
?>
```

Now add your PHTML file in your XML file

> app\design\frontend\Vendor\theme\Magento_Catalog\layout\catalog_product_view.xml

```
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="product.info.main">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="ccolor" template="product/view/ccolor.phtml" />
    </referenceBlock>

    <move element="ccolor" destination="product.info.main" after="product.info.price" />
</body>
```

Flush cache and it should work fine.

Comment: I tried it, cleared all the cache(magento chache, static file cache and storage cache file) but the page is now blank.

Comment: what is your attribute code for "ccolor"?

Comment: the attribute code for ccolor is "color"

Comment: Then you should change in PHTML file. check my updated answer

Comment: Thank you very much, but it still didn't work, here is the piece of code that shows the attributes at More Information tab. I have updated the question to show the code that shows the attributes at More Information Tab.

Comment: I had to clear var/cache, var/composer_home, var/page_cache before it worked.  Thanks