# Magento2 - How to get a custom attribute for catalog product?

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, template, page-layouts, customize

I need to get a custom attribute for catalog products on the product page. I added code,

```
<?php $_getMyAttr = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('my_custom_attr'); ?>
<?php if ($_getMyAttr){ ?>
<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $attrTestValue = $_getMyAttr->getFrontend()->getValue($_product); }?>
```

This works fine when I added to the,

> app/design/frontend/Mgs/ethan/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/type/default.phtml

but does not work when I added to,

> app/design/frontend/Mgs/ethan/Magento_Theme/templates/html/title.phtml

I have also tried to creating a block with the same code and adding that block to my `catalog_product_view.xml` in the directory `app\design\frontend\Mgs\Ethan\Magento_Catalog\layout\catalog_product_view.xml`. But I get a 500 error anytime when I try this.

Is there anything I need to do differently?

catalog_product_view.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
* Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
* See COPYING.txt for license details.
*/
-->
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>



        <referenceBlock name="page.main.title">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">product</argument>
                <argument name="add_base_attribute" xsi:type="string">itemprop="name"</argument>
            </arguments>
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Attributes" name="product.color.attributes" as="additional_color" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/color_attribute.phtml" />
    </referenceBlock>


    <referenceBlock name="head.additional">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="script.sharethis" template="MGS_Mpanel::sharethis/sharethis_script.phtml" ifconfig="mpanel/share_config/share_product_detail"/>
    </referenceBlock>

    <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Title" name="mgs.product.title" template="Magento_Theme::html/title.phtml"/>

    <referenceBlock name="product.info.extrahint" remove="true"/>

    <referenceBlock name="product.info.sku" remove="true"/>

    <move element="mgs.product.title" destination="product.info.main" before="-" />

    <move element="product.info.overview" destination="product.info.main" after="product.addtocaart.form"/>

    <!-- <move element="product.info.price" destination="product.info.main" after="product.brand.name"/> -->

    <container name="product.info.sku.brand" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="product-sub-infomation" after="product.info.review">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="mgs.product.info.sku" template="product/view/attribute.phtml">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getSku</argument>
                <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">sku</argument>
                <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">sku</argument>
                <argument name="at_label" xsi:type="string">default</argument>
                <argument name="add_attribute" xsi:type="string">itemprop="sku"</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </container>



    <move element="product.info.sku.brand" destination="product.info.main" after="product.info.price" />

    <move element="product.brand.name" destination="product.info.sku.brand" after="-" />

    <move element="product.attribute.specs.table" destination="product.info.main" after="product.info.price"/>
</body>
```

Thank you. I have asked this question somewhere else, so when you chance upon that, just ignore it.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/219255/how-to-move-products-attributes-block-after-price/219259#219259

Comment: Yeah, that's me, that didn't work. I tried it a couple of times and came up with this. I did be glad if we can go back there and get the answer right there. I will be glad to mark your answer as correct

Comment: do you want to show all attributes or just specific attributes ?

Comment: just one attribute

Comment: do you want to show it under product price ?

Comment: On top of product name

Comment: I have updated the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To show attribute on product detail page you have to create a template file **color_attribute.phtml** in **Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view** folder.

and add below code in that template file :

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/**
 * Product view template
 *
 * @see \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description
 */
?>

<?php
$_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
$_product = $block->getProduct();

echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('ccolor')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);

?>
```

and place this xml block in catalog_product_view.xml file where ever you want :

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Attributes" name="product.color.attributes" as="additional_color" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/color_attribute.phtml" />
```

for example if you want to show color attribute under title then place this block in page.main.title block .

```
<referenceBlock name="page.main.title">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">product</argument>
        <argument name="add_base_attribute" xsi:type="string">itemprop="name"</argument>
    </arguments>
    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Attributes" name="product.color.attributes" as="additional_color" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/color_attribute.phtml" />
</referenceBlock>
```

**Updated :**

To Add Attribute above product title open catalog_product_view.xml and search for "**product.info.main**" container and then place below code above this container ( `code will be between <referenceContainer name="content"> and "product.info.main" container` )

```
<container name="product-info-main" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="product-attr" before="-">
   <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Attributes" name="product.color.attributes" as="additional_color" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/color_attribute.phtml" before="page.main.title" />
</container>
```

Hope it will work for you

NOTE : you would need to adjust template styling and other parts as per your need.

Comment: Hi, this did not work for me, i don't have these containers in my child theme `<referenceContainer name="content"> and "product.info.main" container`,  i placed the updated version of your answer in my parent theme, but that did not have any effect too. Or I have too run these commands?         
    `*run php bin/magento setup:di:compile command
    *run php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy command
    *run php bin/magento cache:clean command
    *run php bin/magento cache:flush command`

Comment: I have updated my question by adding `catalog_product_view.xml` , I believe that is where my problem is coming from.

Comment: you also need to create template color_attribute.phtml on that path :
Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/, this is the reason you are getting 500 error, since there is no template

Comment: I have created that file `color_attribute.phtml` at the right file path with the content in your answer. I am not getting a 500 error now, there is no change to the page even after clearing cache.

Comment: you have to deploy static content and also you would need to change the attribute code , secondly have you followed all steps which i have written in my answer

Comment: Yes, I have followed what you wrote thoroughly , the only part that i don't really get is your updated version of the answer. `( code will be between <referenceContainer name="content"> and "product.info.main" container )`  because i don't have those containers in my `catalog_product_view.xml`. Also, should the addition be made in `public_html/app/design/frontend/Mgs/ethan/Magento_Catalog/layout` or  `public_html/app/design/frontend/Mgs/mgsblank/Magento_Catalog/layout`.  I hope i am not asking too many questions, i just need more clarification. Thank you

Comment: first of all you need to check which theme is being used, and you have to place the code in that theme's catalog_product_view.xml , if you don't find these blocks in your theme then add block in page.main.title block, like above example : <referenceBlock name="page.main.title">

Comment: I had to clear var/cache, var/composer_home, var/page_cache before it worked. Thanks

Comment: glad to know finally it worked for your :)